# Can I push unrecoverable water well jet down further and install new jet above?

Tags: repair, installation, well-pump

I have a 2" well with 1" pickup pipe inside. When replacing foot it got stuck in casing and the jet assembly broke just below top threaded section. All pickup pipe was recovered along with top threads and the venturi that screws on top of the assembly. Leaving the cast iron foot valve, leathers, and secondary brass foot valve that screws onto bottom of jet assembly stuck inside unrecoverable. Can I just push the unrecovered section down below the original foot valve depth then install new foot valve/jet assembly over the unrecoverable one?

Comment: This *might* be a case where a well service may have tricks and tools to recover what you are not able to recover DIY.

Comment: They want me to just drill another well @ $2500.00 if able to repair will be less than $400.00

Answer (score 0):

If you have room to shove it down and there is enough clearance for the water to pass the old valve it be OK.

Comment: The 2" outer pipe is 120' deep, the 1"  pipe that goes inside the 2" outer pipe is 80' deep. Planning on trying to push old foot valve stuck inside down to at least 90'. Then install new over it back at 80' down. As long as I install a secondary brass foot valve on the new assembly even if the old gets sucked back up to the new it will still allow water to flow through the old. If by chance the old falls will there be enough room in the bottom screen basket for water to flow around/through? Is there going to be an issue with 4 check valves total, possibility of over stressing the pump?

Comment: Explain 4 check valves, the detached one(s) will have no effect on the pump.